# Functional Rust: Why is `filter` borrowing in closure?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

I'm trying to practice using Rust's functional capabilities.

For example, I would like to convert this loop:

```rust
levels: Vec<Vec<u8>> = //< Built by something

let mut total = 0;
for (x, y) in iproduct!(0..10, 0..10) {
    if levels[x][y] > 9 {
        total += count_something(levels, x, y);
    }
}

// Edit: here's the `count_something` function signature
fn count_something (levels: &mut Vec<Vec<u8>>, x: usize, y: usize) -> usize {
    // Count
}
```

This is the result of my functional refactoring:

```rust
iproduct!(0..10, 0..10)
    .filter(|(x, y)| levels[*x][*y] > 9)
    .map(|(x, y)| count_something(levels, x, y))
    .sum()
```

The problem is: this code won't compile.
The error: `error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to *levels but it is already borrowed`.

I don't see why `filter` borrows the `levels` 2D matrix.
My mental model of what is happening under the hood seems inadequate.

Comment: Can you please write a [MRE] ? It's hard to help you without more information, for example how `count_something` is declared (if it needs a mutable reference, then you have your answer)

Comment: Hi @DenysSéguret. I agree with you; asking good questions is the least I can do. That said, I didn't include `count_something` because I thought it was unnecessary details. I'm I mistaken?

Comment: I added the function signature in the question.

Comment: Note that functional programming works poorly with mutable data (in any language, this is not specific to Rust). In pure functional style, `count_something` would take an immutable reference to `levels` and return a modified copy.

Comment: @Jmb interesting point. I didn't though about the non-mutability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't see why filter borrows the levels 2D matrix. My mental model of what is happening under the hood seems inadequate.

`filter`'s callback needs to *access* the matrix, so there's a borrow here (the alternative would be a move): in Rust a closure is syntactic sugar for a struct + a callable, any free variable is automatically transformed to a member of the implicit, anonymous struct:

```rust
.filter(|(x, y)| levels[*x][*y] > 9)
```

becomes (more or less, there's a lot being skipped)

```rust
struct $SECRET1$ {
    levels: &Vec<Vec<u8>>
}
impl $SECRET1$ {
    fn call(&self, x: &usize, y: &usize) -> bool {
        self.levels[*x][*y] > 9
    }
}
[...]
.filter($SECRET1$ { levels: &levels })
```

So that's why `levels` gets borrowed.

The other part of the question would then be why levels is *still* borrowed when the map runs, and the answer is that Rust's iterators are lazy, so they run the operations concurrently (interleaved), not sequentially.

Therefore when you write

```rust
iproduct!(0..10, 0..10)
    .filter(|(x, y)| levels[*x][*y] > 9)
    .map(|(x, y)| count_something(levels, x, y))
    .sum()
```

you're really writing something like:

```rust
let p = iproduct!(0..10, 0..10);
let f = Filter {
    f: |(x, y)| levels[*x][*y] > 9,
    iter: p
};
let m = Map {
    f: |(x, y)| count_something(levels, x, y),
    iter: f
};
Iterator::sum(m)
```

And so as you can see `Map.f` and `Filter.f` exist at the same time and need the same data, which would be fine if both just needed to read from it, but apparently `count_something` (and thus `map`) needs a mutable (unique) reference, and that's not compatible with a readonly (shared) reference.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you